# WooCommerce OrderBy date status complete

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the `wc_get_orders` function to retrieve an order result set, I'm only grabbing orders that are `completed. The ordering of the results by date isn't correct because orders aren't completed in the same order they are created.

```
$orders = wc_get_orders( array(
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'meta_value'        => 'NULL',
    'limit'             => -1,
    'status'            => 'completed',
    'date_completed'    => $start_date.'...'.$end_date,
));
```

How can I re-order by date completed, can I reuse `get_date_completed()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `'meta_key' => '_date_completed',` and `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',`.

Like this:

```
$orders = wc_get_orders( array(
    'meta_key'          => '_date_completed',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'meta_value'        => 'NULL',
    'limit'             => -1,
    'status'            => 'completed',
    'date_completed'    => $start_date.'...'.$end_date,
));
```

Comment: On my test I've removed `'meta_value'        => 'NULL',`, just pointing this out cause i'm not sure if that's intended in your part.

Comment: Thanks, that's work great I didn't think it was stored as meta data! Do you know if there is a way to select specific columns inside `wc_get_orders()`